# Performance Issue: Latency Spike happens sometimes in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am doing Performance Testing in Kafka Streaming. I created a simple Streams API with Transformer.

```
  // Stream data from input topic
  builder.stream(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), inTopic)
         // convert csv data to avro
         .transformValues(new TransformSupplier())
         // post converted data to output topic
         .to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ByteArray(), outTopic);
```

I am using **inTopic** with 10 partitions and **outTopic** with 1 partition. I am seeing latency is good and around ~4-6 ms . But, I am facing sudden spike in the latency sometimes and it reaches even upto ~60 - 1000 ms. Then after few seconds, it gradually dropped latency down back to ~4-6 ms. This results in the average latency for my whole experiment to ~67 ms.

What could be the reason for the sudden spike? Suggest me some performance tuning parameters if any.

Note: I have provided default StreamsConfig only.

Comment: How ofter/regular do those spikes occur? Maybe it's related to StreamsConfig parameter `commit.interval.ms` that is 30 seconds by default?

Comment: I am seeing this atleast once within a minute. I will try changing this parameter also. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After some amount of msgs producing, the data should be flushed to the disk.

This may cause the phenomenon you observed.

Please refer to the "log.flush.interval.messages" of kafka configuration: [Link](http://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html)

After in prod, I do not recommend you to change this property to improve. You should change your system conf:

```
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
```

To improve the efficiency of your own msgs flush

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hash.  Below is my kafka configuration. Looks like flush interval messages is pretty big. Share you view on this. 
        log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.interval.ms = null
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000